# My early 2008 MacBookPro has a different DVI and the adaptor I need is not in stock anywhere

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, appletv, dvi

My early 2008 MacBookPro has a different DVI to later 2008 and the adaptor I need is not in stock anywhere

I am considering putting Apple TV from my Humax to enable my MacBook Pro to link wirelessly

Comment: pictures would help - so we can see what the difference might be. There are, I think, 6 possibilities for a DVI plug/socket.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, it is called Micro DVI.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-DVI

It looks like it can be found here.

[image: micro]

http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=micro+dvi+to+vga+adapter&tag=googhydr-20&index=electronics&hvadid=25104013878&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=474849483470589268&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_4bxv9jd5o7_b

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the early 2008 MacBook Pros have a dual-link DVI socket, and don't need an adaptor at all for DVI output, just a DVI-D cable. The late 2008 models have Mini Display-Port, and need an adaptor to do DVI. Note, however, that DVI only carries video, not audio, so you'll need separate audio cabling if you want to do audio.